# Deserialización de un XML en XAMARIN

Tags: c#, xml, xamarin

estoy tratando de deserializar un XML, más según el debug ya lo logre con exito más no sabría como acceder a los datos que me retorna la deserialización en el modelo, es decir no puedo ver los datos en el objeto que retorna el xml deserializado. No sé si el error esta en la deserialización del XML, en como tengo estructurado el modelo.

Este sería el método donde deserializo el xml y en questiondata se supone que estan mis datos:

```
 public async Task<Applications> getAllServices() //Método (GET) para traer el xml con todos los servicios
    {
        string url = GlobalVariables.URL_SERVICES;
        var content = await client.GetStringAsync(url);

        using (var stream = new StringReader(content))
        {
            var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Applications));
            var questionData = serializer.Deserialize(stream);

            //return questionData;
            return applications;
        }
    }
```

Este sería mi modelo:

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

//Class to desearialize xml to all services in eureka server
namespace Training_In_Media.Models
{
    [XmlRootAttribute(ElementName = "applications")]
    public class Applications
    {
        [XmlElementAttribute("application")]
        public List<Application> application { get; set; }
    }

    public class Application
    {
        [XmlElementAttribute("name")]
        public string nombre { get; set; }

        [XmlElementAttribute("instance")]
        public List<XmlResult> xmlResult { get; set; }
    }

    public class XmlResult
    {
        [XmlElementAttribute("ipAddr")]
        public string ip { get; set; }

        [XmlElementAttribute("port")]
        public int port { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Y este sería un fragmento de mi XML:

```
<applications>
<application>
    <name>CLIENTEDGESERVICE</name>
    <instance>
        <instanceId>vps806035.ovh.net:ClientEdgeService:8075</instanceId>
        <hostName>vps806035.ovh.net</hostName>
        <app>CLIENTEDGESERVICE</app>
        <ipAddr>193.70.42.35</ipAddr>
        <status>UP</status>
        <overriddenstatus>UNKNOWN</overriddenstatus>
        <port enabled="true">8075</port>
        <securePort enabled="false">443</securePort>
        <countryId>1</countryId>
        <dataCenterInfo class="com.netflix.appinfo.InstanceInfo$DefaultDataCenterInfo">
            <name>MyOwn</name>
        </dataCenterInfo>
        <leaseInfo>
            <renewalIntervalInSecs>30</renewalIntervalInSecs>
            <durationInSecs>90</durationInSecs>
            <registrationTimestamp>1586391636340</registrationTimestamp>
            <lastRenewalTimestamp>1586896750323</lastRenewalTimestamp>
            <evictionTimestamp>0</evictionTimestamp>
            <serviceUpTimestamp>1586391636340</serviceUpTimestamp>
        </leaseInfo>
        <metadata>
            <management.port>8075</management.port>
        </metadata>
        <homePageUrl>http://vps806035.ovh.net:8075/</homePageUrl>
        <statusPageUrl>http://vps806035.ovh.net:8075/actuator/info</statusPageUrl>
        <healthCheckUrl>http://vps806035.ovh.net:8075/actuator/health</healthCheckUrl>
        <vipAddress>ClientEdgeService</vipAddress>
        <secureVipAddress>ClientEdgeService</secureVipAddress>
        <isCoordinatingDiscoveryServer>false</isCoordinatingDiscoveryServer>
        <lastUpdatedTimestamp>1586391636340</lastUpdatedTimestamp>
        <lastDirtyTimestamp>1586391636259</lastDirtyTimestamp>
        <actionType>ADDED</actionType>
    </instance>
</application>
```

Me es de importancia obtener la Ip y el puerto que esta en cada application.

Comment: Probaste con hacer la clase completa? quizas te esta fallando porque al faltarle propiedades quiere igualar el objeto al xml y no puede.

Comment: A que te refieres con usar la clase completa? En no dividirla cómo está?

Comment: estas mostrando una clase con dos propiedades y el xml veo que tiene mas propiedades.

Comment: Ok vale, muchas gracias